# Flask reset global dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, global-variables

I am making a tic tac toe in Flask for learning purpose. The board is represented as dictionary and is a global variable. I want to have a button that "resets" the board to be empty so the user can play again, however my code does not work (it executes without error but the board stays the same)

The html button calls the /reset which is executed, however the board values are not changed.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!

```
theBoard = {1:' ', 2:' ', 3:' ', 4: ' ', 5:' ', 6: ' ', 7:' ', 8:' ', 9:' '}

@app.route('/reset', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reset():
    for i in range (1,9):
         theBoard[i] == ' '
    return render_template("test.html", theBoard=theBoard)

@app.route('/play', methods=["GET","POST"])
def test1():
     return render_template("test.html", theBoard=theBoard)

@app.route('/play1', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def test():
    if gameover(theBoard):
       True
       return 'the game is over1'
    else:
        x = request.form['move']
        move = int(x)
        valid_moves = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    if move not in valid_moves:
        return 'you did not specify a valid move, please try again!'
    elif theBoard[move] != ' ':
        return 'you can not play that space, it is taken'
    else:
        theBoard[move] = 'X'
        if gameover(theBoard):
            True
            return 'the game is over2'
        if winning_X(theBoard):
        <and much more code - this part works>
```

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="enter name">
   <form action="/play1" method="POST">
    <lable>Please specify your move (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)</lable>
    <input type="number" name="move" value"">
    <input type="submit" value="Make your move!">
    </form>
</div>
<div>
<table border="1">
<tr id="row1">



    {% if theBoard[1]!=' ' %}
    <td><h1>{{ theBoard[1] }} </h1></td>
    {% else %}
    <td><h1>&nbsp;1&nbsp;</h1></td>
    {% endif %}

    {% if theBoard[2]!=' ' %}
    <td><h1>{{ theBoard[2] }} </h1></td>
    {% else %}
    <td><h1>&nbsp;2&nbsp;</h1></td>
    {% endif %}

    {% if theBoard[3]!=' ' %}
    <td><h1>{{ theBoard[3] }} </h1></td>
    {% else %}
    <td><h1>&nbsp;3&nbsp;</h1></td>
    {% endif %}

<tr id="row2">
    {% if theBoard[4]!=' ' %}
    <td><h1>{{ theBoard[4] }} </h1></td>
    {% else %}
    <td><h1>&nbsp;4&nbsp;</h1></td>
    {% endif %}
    {% if theBoard[5]!=' ' %}
    <td><h1>{{ theBoard[5] }} </h1></td>
    {% else %}
    <td><h1>&nbsp;5&nbsp;</h1></td>
    {% endif %}

    {% if theBoard[6]!=' ' %}
    <td><h1>{{ theBoard[6] }} </h1></td>
    {% else %}
    <td><h1>&nbsp;6&nbsp;</h1></td>
    {% endif %}

<tr id="row3">
    {% if theBoard[7]!=' ' %}
    <td><h1>{{ theBoard[7] }} </h1></td>
    {% else %}
    <td><h1>&nbsp;7&nbsp;</h1></td>
    {% endif %}
    {% if theBoard[8]!=' ' %}
    <td><h1>{{ theBoard[8] }} </h1></td>
    {% else %}
    <td><h1>&nbsp;8&nbsp;</h1></td>
    {% endif %}

    {% if theBoard[9]!=' ' %}
    <td><h1>{{ theBoard[9] }} </h1></td>
    {% else %}
    <td><h1>&nbsp;9&nbsp;</h1></td>
    {% endif %}
</table>
</div>

<div class="reset">
<form action="/reset" method="GET">
    <lable>Do you wanna play again?</lable>
    <button>Play!</button>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you also share the relevant snippet of the markup you're using to publish the board?

Comment: @joemurphy I assume you mean the html? (sorry am still learning). Added it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is causing the error from what i can see:

```
theBoard[i] == ' '
```

The above is actually performing a comparison not assignment, change it to :

```
theBoard[i] = ' '
```

Comment: Sorry didn't saw your answer a while back!

Answer (score 3):

> The html button calls the /reset which is executed, however the board values are not changed.

```
def reset():
    for i in range (1,9):
         theBoard[i] == ' '   # <--- This line
    return render_template("test.html", theBoard=theBoard)
```

You used `==` which is for comparison that returns either `True` or `False`, what you want is the `=` operator (assignment operator, single equal sign), so: `theBoard[i] = ' '`